# SWIG TCL : Renaming the class constructor name from new_* to create_*

Tags: tcl, swig

Can we rename constructors like we rename functions using the %rename directive?

```
%rename(create_cell) Cell(string);
```

Basically, I want to end up with something like `create_cell` instead of `new_Cell`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you can't at that point (did you try it to see if it works?) but there are a few things you can do. (Only do one of them, of course.)

1. Edit the generated code (SWIG writes the C++–Tcl binding code that is then compiled) so that the string `"new_Cell"` is `"create_cell"`. I think you should be able to find the place to change in an argument a function call like Tcl_CreateCommand or `Tcl_CreateObjCommand`, but might also be in a macro depending on how the code generation is done. (I've never actually looked.)
2. Use `load` to get the code into Tcl and then `rename` the command afterwards. Names are not fixed in stone. The `load` *might* be inside the implementation of a call to `package require`; just do what you would normally do to get the code working with the wrong name first, and then do this:

   ```tcl
   rename new_Cell create_cell
   ```
3. Add a wrapper command or procedure; any of these will do:

   ```tcl
   proc create_cell args {
       eval new_Cell $args
   }
   ```

   ```tcl
   # With 8.5 or later
   proc create_cell args {
       new_Cell {*}$args
   }
   ```

   ```tcl
   # With 8.6
   proc create_cell args {
       tailcall new_Cell {*}$args
   }
   ```

   ```tcl
   # Or do this; not a procedure, an alias
   interp alias  {} create_cell  {} new_Cell
   ```

Comment: If you're using a wrapper or alias, you can also use `rename` to move the wrapped `new_Cell` to another Tcl namespace where it won't interfere so much with what you're seeing. Purely cosmetic, but convenient. (Myself, I'd wrap everything because I don't really like the interface style that SWIG produces; Tcl _isn't_ C++ and its APIs have their own flavor.)

Comment: Thanks Donal, I think I will just rename the proc is TCL. That seems to be the simplest thing to do.